# How to create a like gate for a Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'm absolutely new to coding and am trying to add a like gate to my Facebook app (a simply blog feed created using a wordpress plugin)

I really want to make a like gate for the app... ideally it would be an ajax style popup that greys out the content until the page is liked, or a transparent graphic which does the same.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I'm completely stuck!

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+facebook+app+fan+gate

Comment: Absolutely useless input, I wouldn't have asked on here if i hadn't tried to Google it first... either help or don't say anything.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a topic that has already been broadly discussed – here on SO and on the net. If you are still not able to figure it out and are “completely stuck” … then I don’t see how we could possible help you – short from writing your code for you.

Comment: if you know any good posts that explains the question well that would help... if you don't know any then perhaps you should leave the topic alone.

Comment: Keyword for further search: signed_request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like-Gates are usually in App Tabs, where it's possible to check if the user liked the page without forcing the user to authorize your app first. So your first step is to research how to use **signed_request** to determine if the page has been liked. If the page isn't liked, show the ajax popup. For the 'ajax-style-popup' you can use something like [leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au)